# Ignoring Validation on a Button

Tags: javascript, xpages

I'm adding a "Cancel" button to an XPage that has a form with many required fields. When I click the "Cancel" button, it runs through the validation and gives me the errors. Is there code I can put inside the Cancel button that will ignore the validation requirements and simply go back to the previous page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every event supports two options for bypassing validation:

[image: Event Properties]

Select "Process data without validation" to update the data model (i.e. document) and run the event code without executing any validators

Select "Do not validate or update data" to run the event code without running validators *or* updating the data model. This latter option is ideal for cancellation buttons.